# MYSQL - count occurrence of variable in specific columns only

Tags: mysql, sql

I searched for this answer but couldn't find anything.  Hoping for a little help.

> Query Needed:  How many times does each number appear in each column.

tableName = "Schedule"

```
+-----+-------+-----------+-------+
| key | prime | secondary | third |
+-----+-------+-----------+-------+
|   1 |     6 |         6 |     7 |
|   2 |     7 |         9 |     9 |
|   3 |     6 |         9 |     6 |
|   4 |     9 |         9 |     9 |
+-----+-------+-----------+-------+
```

I would like my results to be a count of each occurrence in each column...

```
+--------+------ +-----------+-------+
| number | prime | secondary | third |
+--------+-------+-----------+-------+
|     6  |     2 |         1 |     1 | 
|     7  |     1 |         0 |     1 |
|     9  |     1 |         3 |     2 | 
+-------+-----------+--------+-------+
```

So the #6 is occurs 2x in "prime" column, occurs 1x in the "secondary" column and occurs 1x in the "third" column.

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select nall.id,
    (select count(*) from Schedule where prime = nall.id) as prime,
    (select count(*) from Schedule where secondary = nall.id) as secondary,
    (select count(*) from Schedule where third = nall.id) as third
from
    (select prime as id from Schedule 
    union
    select secondary as id from Schedule 
    union
    select third as id from Schedule ) nall;
```

Answer (score 1):

Get all the distinct numbers from the three columns using `union`. `left join` the `count` of each column to these numbers to get the final result.

```
select all_nums.num,coalesce(p_cnt,0), coalesce(s_cnt,0), coalesce(t_cnt,0) 
from 
(select prime as num from t union select secondary from t union select third from t) all_nums
left join 
(select prime,count(*) as p_cnt from t group by prime) p on p.prime=all_nums.num
left join
(select secondary,count(*) as s_cnt from t group by secondary) s on s.secondary=all_nums.num
left join
(select third,count(*) as t_cnt from t group by third) t on t.third=all_nums.num
group by all_nums.num
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this...  The query worked nicely, as a novice I will have to dissect the query and learn from this.  mcNets also created a more simple (to understand) query... :)  As, I'm unsure about efficiency/speed and my table is relatively small.. I accepted mcNets Thank you again.